# How to create variables from a list of their names in python?

Tags: python, pandas, finance

So I have:

```
    ticker_list = ['aapl','nvda','pglc']
    for ticker in ticker_list:
        ticker_price = create_dataframe( path, ticker )
```

Where **`create_dataframe( path, ticker )`** is a custom function that creates a pandas data frame out of daily price data that includes various calculations such as moving average, RSI, etc.

The last line is where my issue is. I'm trying to create a series of variables with the names:

```
aapl_price
nvda_price
pglc_price
```

etc.

Each of these variables would be a pandas data frame with a bunch of columns that I can then pass to another function later on.

How do I get automatically generate these variable names? I've seen several answered questions where they're trying to associate a single value with a name, and they're answered by telling them to use a dictionary to make that association instead, but I'm not sure that's possible with a pandas data frame.

Comment: create a dict string for key, df for value, see dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036700/how-can-you-dynamically-create-variables-via-a-while-loop

Comment: The solution is still a dictionary.

Comment: You can enumerate into some tuples. Or use a dictionary: `.to_dict()`